# How to measure a servlet's running time?

Tags: java, http, url, servlets, time

I am creating a little tool to measure a java servlet's running time. The servlet gives an EPS type image on the outputstream (so if I call the servlet from a browser an EPS image downloads or a download window pops up - depends on the settings).

I would like to measure the servlet's running time with my tool: I call the servlet for example 10000 times then count an average.

**My problem is:** I want to avoid counting expensive I/O operations so I'd like to download the EPS per every single servlet call, but don't want to save them on my HDD.

I have written this code:

```
        long startTime = System.nanoTime();
        try {
            URLConnection connection = new URL(url + "?" + query).openConnection();
            connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", charset);
            InputStream response = connection.getInputStream();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Connection failed!");
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(0);
        }
        long endTime = System.nanoTime();
        long deltaTime = endTime - startTime;
```

Does it do what I want? Or should I do something with the imputsream? Does the EPS image download per every servlet call? I know they aren't saved, but do they download?

Thanks!

Comment: The code gets a reference to the `InputStream` but does not read out data from it (which, in turn would make the actual download run). Thus I think it only measures the time needed to establish the connection and get some first data downloaded, at most until the client-side buffers fill up. EDIT: For small pictures, this might give good results. For large ones, almost definitely not. I'd also say you're right about the need to avoid client-side HDD operations. To do so, I'd read out the input stream completely and throw away the data.

Comment: It's hard to say. You measure the time for the response to start, but you aren't measuring the transmission time. I would suggest writing a TimingServlet then you can setup a [chain](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/java-ent/servlet/ch02_05.htm).

Comment: Many thanks for the both of you! I will examine your suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just read the inputstream and discard the data:

```
byte [] buffer = new byte[4096];
while (input.read(buffer) != -1);
```